# Integration in Website / website personalization

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, integration, website-integration

As a webportal we are already using Marketing Cloud heavily for email/sms and push notifications.

We are currently working on the personalization of our portal for registered customers. In the feature we would like to be able to display some content-components for certain users (pop-ups, alerts, content-blocks, etc.)

However, as we love the Journey Builder for building segments, ideally we would find a way to integrate the journey builder with our portal, so we would be able to segment customers based on salesforce data and enter users to certain content-elements that then will displayed in the portal.

We already did some research but haven't found any use case. Is there any third-party integration we could use? If not, any experience in a custom developed solution?

Comment: I think you need to explain more clearly how Journey Builder specifically relates to your goals. You said you use it for segmentation, but it sounds like you want to utilize that segmentation for your web portal. 

I imagine you could update contact data in linked data extensions during a subscriber's journey and then use the REST API to query that data on your microsite. Is that what you're after?